# Use C-z to suspend/resume console emacs?

Tags: emacs

How can I configure console emacs so it can be suspended/backgrounded with `C-z` when it's being run from the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it should work by default. Have you bound C-z to a function? That might be overriding it.

As a test, try running Emacs in a terminal, with no init file loaded:

```
emacs -q -nw
```

C-z properly suspends for me.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Ya, it looks like elscreen has grabbed it.

Answer (score 2):

With `elscreen`, use `C-x C-z`, which is just an alternative to `C-z`. Read elscreen help !